# background image for navigation link

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display a background image behind the navigation link, but it is not displayed completely this is the code:

```
#aboutlink{
   background-image: url(sidebar.png); 
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: left;
   background-color: transparent; 
   display: block; 
   margin-bottom: 160px;
   text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the width and height of the navigation link, otherwise the image will be cut off and won't display fully

Answer (score 1):

Set width and height to match the size of the background image. The reason the image is being "cut off" is because the background image isn't taken into account as it automatically calculates the width and height to only be as big as it needs to be.